# calling "- (void) takePicture" returns non-foucsed image

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an UIImagePickerController with my own camera overlay. In that overlay I have a button that the user can press to take a photo.

Currently, I have an IBAction on "Touch Up Inside" that will take a picture. self.imagePickerController is my reference to UIImagePickerController

```
- (IBAction)onSnapClicked:(id)sender {

     [self.imagePickerController takePicture];

}
```

My problem is that, in the callback method. The image that I get back is always blurry. Please help

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{   
    // Get the original image
    UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same quality. You might have created a lag somewhere thus gives you the false sense of finish taking picture, while it is actually capturing.

Unless your button allows touch through. In that case, the camera always try to focus that part of your picture. You have to prevent that from happening. How to do that, look into my answer on this question : [Exlusive touch in cameraoverlay view (of the camerapicker) in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898758/exlusive-touch-in-cameraoverlay-view-of-the-camerapicker-in-ios/11672147#11672147)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Byte, I've double checked my code and I realized that I was passing in a scaled down version of my picture in my own preview view. the Picture was 320x640 and I was displaying this on my iPhone4. No wonder it was blurry.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I could not have foreseen it in your question :) glad you resolved it.